# Rest Api Data Representation

Tags: json, xml, rest

I hava an Spring Boot Rest Api

```
@RestController
public class BookController {

@Autowired
private BookRepository bookRepo;

@GetMapping(value = "/library/", produces ={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
public List<Book> index(){
    Iterable<Book> bookIterable = bookRepo.findAll();
    List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();
    bookIterable.forEach(a->bookList.add(a));
    return bookList;
}
```

My Homework is to add an additonal data representation so that when i put in the request i should can choose between which data representation i won't XML or JSON

Problem is [image: Header Data Representation Options]

I get even json how can i change between XML and Json when i do a get Request to the Endpoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your problem you need to use the `Accept` header. [more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept)

The `Content Type` header indicates the type of data that you pass in the request. [more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type)

You need to make a request with the header, if you want to send and receive xml:

```
 Accept: application/xml;
 Content-Type: application/xml;
```

[usefull link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6PEW_9.4.0/com.ibm.help.custom.restapis.doc/c_SpecifyingHTTPHeaders.html)

Comment: YES thank you! Now Exception is thrown. Could not find acceptable representation

Answer (score 0):

Ok now i found it my self what you need to know in order to use an XML output is first add 
to the pom.xml file following dependencies: Jackson XML Dataformat

```
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
           <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
           <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

Then i just have to Add Jackson Annotations to my Entity Class



   @Entity
   @JacksonXmlRootElement
   public class Book {
    public Book() {
    }
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String title;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private Integer numberOfCopies;
```

Thats it then i can Make a request with the Accept Header value application/xml